# ENUM module and cStringIO module in PYVISA

Tags: python, python-3.x, visa, gpib, cstringio

I have some trouble to fix. I am using Python 3.2 with `pyvisa` for Python 3.2 32bits. When i used:

```
import pyvisa
```

It displayed:

```
ImportError: No module named enum
```

But when I use:

```
import pyqtgraph, pyvisa
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named cStringIO
```

I just want to use `pyvisa` for using an Agilent 33250a by GPIB.

Answer (score 0):

The [`enum` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) wasn't part of Python until Python 3.4, so 3.2 is too early; you need to upgrade, or you need to live without `enum` (upgrading is a good idea mind you; the performance and features of Python have improved markedly since then; on performance in particular, [strings and user defined class instances dramatically reduced their memory overhead](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393)). I'm guessing `pyvisa` dropped support for Python versions older than 3.4 if they're depending on `enum`.

`cStringIO` is a Python 2.x only accelerator module for `StringIO`; in Python 3.0 and higher, you just import `io` and use `io.StringIO`, and it will automatically use the C accelerated code under the hood when available, and pure Python code otherwise. If you're only targeting Python 3, just do `import io` or `from io import StringIO`. For code that should run under both Python 2 and Python 3, and use `str` in both, you can do the following for imports:

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO  # Py2 C accelerated version
except ImportError:
    try:
        from StringIO import StringIO  # Py2 fallback version
    except ImportError:
        from io import StringIO  # Py3 version
```

If you want to handle Unicode text regardless of Python version (well, in 2.6 and up), you can just use `io.StringIO` exclusively; it works with `unicode` in Py2, and `str` in Py3, which means it handles all text in both versions (where `cStringIO` only handles `str` in Py2, so it can't handle the whole Unicode range).

I suspect your other import error for `pyqtgraph` would be because you tried installing a version of `pyqtgraph` written for Python 2; the `pyqtgraph` page claims Python 3.x compatibility, and use of `cStringIO` without a fallback would not meet that claim, so either you installed the wrong version, or it was installed incorrectly (e.g. if they were using a single code base and `2to3`-ing it, but you somehow installed it without `2to3`-ing it; no idea how you'd do that).